# Error has occured when starting up spring tool suite

Tags: spring

Can someone help me with these log file? When i started up spring tool suite, it says "an error has occurred. See the log file." How do i fix these issues?

[Log file part 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18y3FAFQRQBwCaSewhCb4On8iVzAYDXxl)

[Log file part 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c4ojQORGOcv7LIVtIHCH8ZOYhxXTBdNT)

Comment: post the logs here please

Comment: @KickButtowski The logs are in the hyperlinks. Are you unable to access it?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Somehow, i managed to fix it. I've followed the stuff on this forum page([Link Here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/823236/)).

What I've done was deleting all of the (lock) files under under "configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager". these files had names starting with .fileTable

After that i managed to start up spring tool suite again. So far nothing seems to be breaking.